# Django custom serializer validation for unique field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write custom invitational system for user registration using DRF. I need separate path  only for checking is code is valid. I'm stuck with serializer returns is_valid = False in case if this code exists in database, because code field is defined as Unique in model. And i need opposite behavior.

Model

```
class InviteCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, unique=True)
    referal = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_referal')
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    used_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_used_by')
```

Serializer

```
class InviteCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InviteCode
        fields = "__all__"
```

I tried to add validate_code() method to serializer for custom validation

```
    def validate_code(self, value):
        code = InviteCode.objects.filter(code = value).first()
        if code is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invite code doesn't exist")
        #Other validation checks
        return code
```

But it is being called after unique check, so in cases when code is present in database method won't be called, and i will still get

```
{'code': [ErrorDetail(string='invite code with this code already exists.', code='unique')]}
```

after calling is_valid on serializer

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the behavior you want, where the serializer's `is_valid` method returns `True` even if the code exists in the database, you can make use of the `validate_unique` method in your serializer. The `validate_unique` method is called after all the individual field-level validation methods have been called, including `validate_code`.

Here's how you can modify your serializer to handle this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class InviteCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InviteCode
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate_code(self, value):
        # Your custom validation checks
        # ...

        return value

    def validate_unique(self, attrs):
        # Check for the uniqueness of code explicitly
        if "code" in attrs:
            code = attrs["code"]
            existing_code = InviteCode.objects.filter(code=code).exists()
            if existing_code:
                # You can raise a validation error here if you want to
                # but in your case, you want to allow duplicate codes
                pass

        # Call the parent's validate_unique method to handle other uniqueness checks
        return super().validate_unique(attrs)
```

By overriding the `validate_unique` method, you can perform your custom uniqueness check for the `code` field and allow duplicate codes without raising a validation error.

This should now allow you to create a serializer with duplicate codes without raising a uniqueness error when calling `is_valid` on the serializer. However, do note that you need to take care of the uniqueness constraint yourself, as Django won't handle it automatically in this case.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I modified code as you mentioned and behavior is still the same. And it seems that method validate_unique() isn't called.

Probably i will remove uniqueness from code field. And will check that it is exist in database in validate_code() method. Plus check for unique during adding new code

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found solution using this approach.
Instead I modified model to remove unique param on code field

```
class InviteCode(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False)
referal = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_referal')
is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
used_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_used_by')
```

And checking is provided code exist in database in serializer validate_code() method

```
class InviteCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = InviteCode
    fields = "__all__"
def validate_code(self, value):
    code = InviteCode.objects.filter(code = value).first()
    if code is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invite code doesn't exist")
    #Other validation checks
    return code
```

Plus added checks for duplicates for admin panel to prevent code duplication during adding through admin panel
admin.py

```
class InviteCodeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
def clean_code(self):
    #check fro duplication here
    return self.cleaned_data["code"]
class AdminInviteCode(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = InviteCodeAdminForm
admin.site.register(InviteCode, AdminInviteCode)
```